# How to inset an extrusion with the rest of the shape?

Tags: faces, tools

Hi I have extruded part of a block but now when I try to inset the top face of that block with the extrusion it insets the top face of the extrusion separately rather than doing it with the rest of the block. How do I inset the whole thing as one object?[image]

Comment: Did you inset all 4 faces simultaneously?

Comment: do you mean like this? [![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po01c.png

Answer (score 2):

Start with a cube.

1. select the cube
2. press S -> Z and scale it flat as you need
3. press S -> Shift Z and scale as you need
4. Tab -> edit mode
5. Face select

[image]

6. press CTRL - R and insert loop cut

[image]

7. scroll up your mouse wheel until you have 2
8. click on mouse twice to confirm
9. select this face

[image]

10. tab E to extrude and extrude as you need

[image]

11. select all top faces

[image]

12. press I and move mouse as you like

[image]

13. now you can extrude again with E if you like

[image]

14. optionally: if you press S and move you mouse you will get:

[image]

video tutorial here:

https://youtu.be/mj6LjXgf5c4